# Excel Grand Total in PivotChart from Data Model

Tags: excel, pivot-table, mdx, powerpivot

**Goal**

Generate a Grand Total column (called *All* below) in a PivotTable to be displayed in a PivotChart in Excel 2016.

**PivotTable Current**

| Sum of DailySales | Column Labels |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Row Labels** | **North** | **South** |
| 1/2/2021 | 1000 | 2000 |
| 1/3/2021 | 1500 | 2500 |

**PivotTable Desired**

| Sum of DailySales | Column Labels |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Row Labels** | **North** | **South** | **All** |
| 1/2/2021 | 1000 | 2000 | 3000 |
| 1/3/2021 | 1500 | 2500 | 4000 |

**Data Insight**

All data is in the Data Model, with a relationship established through *StoreID*.  Data pulls from two tables:

1. Districts

   - StoreID
   - District *(North or South)*
2. Sales

   - StoreID
   - DateStamp
   - DailySales

**Attempts**

- I tried creating a calculated item.  Not possible:  Grayed out.
- I tried using a measure, but it just totals each District separately, repeating values I already have.
- I looked into using Sets through an MDX expression.  This seemed to hold the most promise, as I just need to return (shorthand) [North],[South],[North]+[South].  However, I have never used MDX before and can't figure out a simple sum function to accomplish this.  Creating a set from columns gives me this starting point:

  - {([Districts].[District].&[North]),([Districts].[District].&[South])}

**Solution I hate**
The only way I've figured out how to do this is to create two PivotTables and then combine them through the Wizard into a third.  This creates significant overhead in my document and gets messy with updating.

**Summary**
Any assistance is appreciated.  Thanks for at least sticking with me this far.

Comment: Is the Pivot table on the Excel Worksheet?  At the top menu bar there should be an option `Design`.  Select that and then the `Layout` tab.  There is an item `Grand Totals`.  Set it on for Rows and off for columns

Comment: Unfortunately, Grand Totals don't populate in PivotCharts.

Comment: What about creating a Stacked Chart where the total of the column/bar/whatever would then equate to the grand total for that date?

Comment: I toyed with that, but it's not as obvious a comparison, visually, between the two data sets.  I do appreciate your willingness to engage on ideas, though!

Comment: Create the pivot table in power query. Then add custom column which sums each row.

Comment: I just tested this and it worked.  Not quite how I'd hoped, as there will be a bit of scripting to make update timings fall in line correctly, but it does give me a different method than I've been using.  I'll have to check to see if it's faster, but I have to think it would be.  So for now, I'm willing to mark this as an answer if you want to post it that way.  Thank you!

Comment: Will your desired results table have only the two regions?  Or does that need to be dynamic?

Comment: Just two... no need to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given data samples like below:
[image]

You can create a table in Power query with code:

```
let

//read in the data
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Districts"]}[Content],
    districts = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"StoreID", type text}, {"District", type text}}),
    Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Sales"]}[Content],
    sales = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,
        {{"StoreID", type text},{"DateStamp", type date},{"DailySales", Int64.Type}}),

//Join the two tables
    joined = Table.NestedJoin(districts, "StoreID", sales,"StoreID","joined",JoinKind.FullOuter),

//expand the joined table
//then groupby date
    #"Expanded joined" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(joined, "joined", {"DateStamp", "DailySales"}, {"DateStamp", "DailySales"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Expanded joined", {"DateStamp", "District"}, {{"Values", each List.Sum([DailySales]), type nullable number}}),

//Pivot by District
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[District]), "District", "Values", List.Sum),

//Add a column summing the districts for each date
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "All", each List.Sum({[North],[South]}))
in
    #"Added Custom"
```

Looking like:

[image]

Then **Load to** a pivot chart, and create the chart:

[image]

Comment: One edit:  Load to a **PivotTable**, and create the chart:

Comment: @SaintFrag If you prefer, you can certainly load to a **Pivot Table Report** and create the chart.  But unless you need the **Report** on an Excel worksheet for something else, you can also load directly to a **Pivot Chart**.

Comment: Hmm... I was unaware this was possible... perhaps just not in Excel 2016 from the "Load to..." option?  But, to your point, if I create a connection only query with adding it to the data model and then I can insert a PivotChart and build it.  As a note, this route did double my load time compared to the "Solution I hate" option previously used above.  So I'm not sure this is actually a better route, though way more manageable.